# Change the login/register URL in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently writing an application which only has accounts for staff of the company, not regular website visitors.  As such, I would like to keep my URLs which relate to the 'admin' area of the site, under the /admin URL which means changing `/login` to `/admin/login` and `/register` to `/admin/register`.

However, I'm at a loss as how to change the login and register URLs in Laravel 5.2, it seems that in previous versions it was a simple matter of adding `protected $loginPath = '/admin/login';` to `Auth\AuthController` However, this makes no difference when adding it to my `AuthController`.

The following is the output of `php artisan route:list`;

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name | Action
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       |      | App\Http\Controllers\PageController@index
|        | GET|HEAD | admin                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPageController@index
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/profile           |      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminPageController@profile
|        | GET|HEAD | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm
|        | POST     | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout
|        | POST     | password/email          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLink
|        | POST     | password/reset          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm
|        | GET|HEAD | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationF
|        | POST     | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In L5.2, all authentication routes are grouped in a route called `Route::auth()`.

If you search for the symbol `auth()` , you can see the auth() function which contains all the route links.

Check this file:  `Illuminate\Routing\Router` for the `auth()` function.

But I'm not sure if it's a good practice to change it here.

**Edit:**

> So if you need to change the default auth routes, include all routes
>   in your `routes.php` file and change the uri as you want it.

To get a reference:

```
    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: Thanks.  What would be the best practice of override these values?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to change it here. But wait for someone to confirm.

Comment: It's bad practice to change anything in the `vendor` folder, especially because they will be overwritten any time you run `composer update`. Just define the routes in your routes file.

Answer (score 9):

You can call `Route::auth()` inside a prefixed group.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::auth();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's bad practice to change anything in the vendor folder, especially because they will be overwritten any time you run composer update.**

So Change `Auth::routes();` on `routes/web.php` to

> ```
>     // Authentication Routes...
>     $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
>     $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
>     $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
>
>     // Registration Routes...
>     $this->get('registers', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
>     $this->post('registers', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
>
>     // Password Reset Routes...
>     $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
>     $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
>     $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
>     $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use named routes instead of using `Route::auth();`

```
Route::get('/admin/login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/admin/login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('/admin/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

Answer (score 0):

In `vendor/laravel/ui/src/AuthRouteMethods.php` you can customize urls.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel v9.38.0 (PHP v8.1.6)
You can replace the Auth::routes() with the code below and effect the changes you want.

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register');
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);

//Password Confirm
Route::get('password/confirm', [ConfirmPasswordController::class, 'showConfirmForm'])->name('password.confirm');
Route::post('password/confirm', [ConfirmPasswordController::class, 'confirm']);

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showLinkRequestForm'])->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'sendResetLinkEmail'])->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'showResetForm'])->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'reset'])->name('password.update');
```