# how can change custom messages errors at login action in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm new user that use in `Laravel 5.2` framework.

I have problem to modify Validator error messages at the login `action`. I could change the other part of `action` for example Register , ResetPasspord ...

but i can't find login action. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298174/change-the-login-register-url-in-laravel-5-2) when searched at google but it not help me,

I know that `Laravel` use `Route::auth();` in Route file but where is login action that i can change error message language !?

I test this sample code at `Requests\Request.php` a something this:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'required' => 'test error message',
        'email.unique' => 'test error message',
    ];
}
```

but it wasn't any change !!!

I dont like change action sample login in laravel, and create my custom login, i  wanna modify validator custom messages in all app or part of login action

I'm sorry if my language english was not prefect

Thank you

Comment: login action you can find in App\Auth\authController. However, you can change default messages from files in Resources\lang\en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One:** In `config/app.php` change

```
'locale' => 'en' to 'locale' => 'es'
```

**Two:** copy all files in the directory `resources/lang/en` to `resources/lang/es`

**Three:** changes the language messages in the file `resources/lang/es/validation.php`

e.g.

```
'required' => 'El :attribute es requerido.',
```

Comment: hi, i should do any 3 section step by step that you answered or it is 3 way seprate and apiece is a way for solved my problem?

Comment: you must do the three steps to create custom validations for each language you want to add

Answer (score 3):

Laravel uses files in `resources/lang/en/validation.php` (if using english) to determine what to echo. There you'll find your messages and can change them to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Include  this in your Request 
Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator

/**
* Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
*
* @return array
*/

```
public function messages()
```

{
`return` [

```
'title.required' => 'A title is required',
'body.required' => 'A message is required',
];

}
```

It will make you to get custom messages.